# Is it possible to modify the prompt according to the existence of a VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, bashrc, prompt, vpnc, ps1

When away from home, I like to connect to the internet via VPN. It would be great to see whether the connection is on in my prompt, for example:

```
frank@mycomputer ~    # without vpn active
frank@mycomputerVPN ~ # when vpn is active
```

How can I my `.bashrc` so that the existence of the connection is evaluated every time the prompt appears? Setting PS1 with the vpnc startup script is not the solution, because it sometime dies. So I check whether

```
ps ax -o comm| grep [v]pnc
```

gives back some result.

Any solution possible?

Answer (score 2):

#### Add the result of a test to your prompt

If the command `ps ax -o comm| grep [v]pnc` gives no output whatsoever when there is no active vpn connection, but *it does* when there is, you could edit your `.bashrc` file by:

1. adding the following small section to it:

   ```
   if [ -z "$(ps ax -o comm| grep [v]pnc)" ]; then
       test="no vpn active"
   else
       test="vpn active"
   fi
   ```
2. Then find the lines, starting with:

   ```
   PS1='${debian_chroot....
   ```
3. Add `($test)` in fromt of `${debian_chroot`:

   ```
   PS1='($test) ${debian_chroot...
   ```

Then the result is:

[image]

when there is an active connection, and:

[image]

when there isn't.

#### Note

Always first backup your `~/.bashrc` before editing.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

I created a shell script named "/usr/local/bin/isvpn" with this content:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ -z "$(ifconfig | grep tun)" ]; then
    test="no VPN"
else
    test="VPN"
fi
echo -n "$test"
```

In the .bashrc now I have the line

```
PS1="\u@\h [\$(isvpn)]\w \$ "
```

So it works as intended. In addition you can emphasize the prompt with colours.
Maybe this can help someone else.